# ASIHTTPRequest synchronously

Tags: iphone, asihttprequest

I have an iPhone app which uses ASIHTTPRequest to communicate to a REST service on my server. When I'm running on the simulator, it works just fine, but when I get onto the phone itself, I get weird behavior.

The very first time I click the button that initiates the request, I get the results back immediately, and all is fine. From that point on, when I click the button to initiate the connection it takes about 2-3 minutes to connect. It almost seems like the ASIHTTPRequest that I kicked off first (and from which I've already received the correct results) has not completed. Is there some sort of magic I need to use to terminate the original request before starting the next one? I assumed that since the -start method returned, and I have results from the server that the original request was completed and I could start another.

Any ideas?

Thanks

--Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not suppose to call the -start method, it belongs to the NSOperation. The ASIHTTPRequest interface is either -startSynchronous or -startAsynchronous.

However, it's highly recommend to use the asynchronous call otherwise, your main thread (ie., UI) will be blocked.

From the ASIHTTPRequest documentation[1]

> In general, you should use
>   asynchronous requests in preference to
>   synchronous requests. When you use
>   ASIHTTPRequest synchronously from the
>   main thread, your application's user
>   interface will lock up and become
>   unusable for the duration of the
>   request. Synchronous requests are only
>   really suitable for software without a
>   UI (like a script that runs from the
>   terminal), or if you are running the
>   request from a separate thread that
>   you maintain (perhaps from inside your
>   own NSOperation, for example).

[1] http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use

Comment: The version of ASIHTTPRequest I haddownloaded back in December didn't have the startSynchronous method, only the -start method. 

I've downloaded the most recent version of ASIHTTPRequest, and changed the code to use startSynchronous, but the effect is the same.

Comment: Switching to startAsynchronous  hasn't helped. The first call goes through, every subsequent call fails with a "A connection failure occurred". The underlying error is a timeout.

Comment: I've changed the code so that each ASIHTTPRequest runs on a seperate queue. Now it works about 50% of the time, the rest of the time it times out.

This is becoming frustrating. Should I just give up on ASIHTTPRequest for the phone and go back to NSURLConnection to make this work?

Comment: Why don't you set the timeOutSeconds of ASIHTTPRequest much longer?

Comment: Another reason why I faced this was because my testing server http://localhost/nameOfMyServer was not accessible to my phone. so i had to Goto Settings > Wifi > MyNetwork > ManualProxy > IP of my Desktop and then try

Answer (score 6):

Steve - What you've described is a common problem that will occur if the requests are attempting to keep a persistent connection. Try this out:

```
[request setShouldAttemptPersistentConnection:NO];
```